# Do Gauntlets have spell failure?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I have a Wizard 5/Fighter 1 character who likes to fight in melee. He's got Gauntlets of Destruction to give him more strength. I've been trying to find spell failure for gauntlets alone, but was only able to find it for locked gauntlets (I'm pretty sure Gauntlets of Destruction aren't locked?)

Do non-locked gauntlets by themselves have spell failure? If yes, what's the chance?

Comment: Hi Creature; if this is your Wizard 5 / Fighter 1 character - and not another character who is just Wizard 5 - it's worth mentioning his Fighter level, since that might affect the answer.

Comment: @doppelgreener It is the Fighter 1 character. Thanks!

Comment: @doppelgreener how?

Comment: @Zachiel a 3.5e expert I am not, but is it unreasonable of me to assume that another class's features have a vague possibility of introducing an exception or edge case, especially when those class features can involve a bunch of weapon and armor proficiencies? Better be safe and communicate about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gauntlets of Destruction (MIC, p.192) are stated to be spiked gauntlets.
While gauntlets in general could be part of an armor and any kind of glove can substitute the armor's original gauntlets, they are a weapon and not a suit of armor. Therefore, **they don't give you Arcane Spell Failure at all.**

Gauntlets, while being a weapon, allow you to move your fingers and use items and cast spells and count as having that hand free for casting purposes. (This is not crystal clear in the rules but the opposite is never stated when the rules talk about heavier armors and spellcasting in the base manual -unlike chained gauntlets- so I suppose it was the designer's intent to make it possible to cast while wearing gauntlets.)

Comment: Rather funny, if you look at the picture or read the fluff. Yep, those huge decorated spiky steel gauntlets don't make it any harder to gesture or rummage through a spell component pouch...

Comment: I guess, although it would be unpopular, the DM could rule a concentration check, which he would probably be making anyway depending on other circumstances?

Comment: @Ernir - but a Mithril chain vest **can** cause you problems. Go figure.